# S6 - slow startup service incorrectly starts second time

Tags: linux, init.d

I'm using s6 (http://skarnet.org/software/s6/) in order to supervise processes.

I have this working well for hundreds of processes across dozens of docker instances and servers.  I have a new problem on an otherwise stable system.

I set up a service for ClamAV and in /etc/services.d/clamv/run I start the process with:

```
exec s6-setuidgid clamav /opt/clamd
```

It starts up, but clam has a long startup cycle and after about one minute 20 seconds (presumably when it completes loading the database) S6 starts *another* instance of clam.  I can see them with ps:

```
2286 clamav     0:00 /opt/clamd 
5091 clamav     0:58 /opt/clamd
```

After that has completed loading, the second instance tries to use the socket and triggers an error:

```
Socket file /run/clamav/clamd.sock is in use by another process
```

Interestingly, using ps aux - the TIME colum for the first process increases to 1:18 and then returns to zero - and the second instance then counts up in the same way.

If I leave it running, when the second process has completed startup, s6 appears to attempt to start another - though curiously, no additional processes appear using ps aux.

I have confirmed that clam only creates the sock and pid files after the long startup.

Obvious question - how do I fix this so that s6 does not start a second instance at the end of the long startup.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is unrelated to s6 - I had the clamd.conf file in the wrong place so it was picking up the incorrect settings.  The clamd default is to run in the background - so s6 was unable to supervise the process.

With clam starting in the foreground, everything worked as it should.